# How can text new line when scale textview?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on `TextView` as like Sticker View.I am successfully done but I can not wrap as I want. I want like this [please check this clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8tcs2ozplj7hz1/RPReplay_Final1642920047.mov?dl=0) and I am getting this output please check this [output clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyenn5zp3cikhjo/RPReplay_Final1642920936.mov?dl=0). From 1st clip I want like that and second video I am getting that.

In 1st video you can see when scaling the `TextView` It doesn't scale with center and when panning from right side of the `TextView` you can see it will decrease/increase width only.

In 2nd video(This is I am getting) you can see when scaling the `TextView` it will scale from the center that I don't want.

I want scale like 1st video. Hope you are understand.

I'm using this code

```
@objc func scaleGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: superview)
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        initialBounds = bounds
    }
    if recognizer.state == .changed {
        let horizontalChange = recognizer.translation(in: self).x
        let verticalChange = recognizer.translation(in: self).y
        bounds = CGRect(x: initialBounds!.origin.x, y: initialBounds!.origin.y, width: initialBounds!.width + horizontalChange, height: initialBounds!.height + verticalChange)
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear to me, from the videos, what you want; please describe.  What is "stiker"?

Comment: @meaning-matters Please check my updated question.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I think you should set `frame`, not `bounds`.

Comment: @meaning-matters Can you please give an example for me? I will help me a lot